# PDF viewer that reads all files in a folder continuously

Tags: gratis, osx, pdf-viewer

Looking for a PDF viewer that can do the follow

- given a folder that contains PDF files
- open the first file in the folder (alphabetical order)
- continue to open the next file in the folder once move past the last page of current file

Additional good to have feature

- Able to jump to different files in the list and start viewing from that file
- Able to define a list of files in order

It should be  [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis)

Platform : OS X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preview can do that. Select all the pdf files you want to open (in the order you want them to open as), then double-click them. It will go to the second file once the first one ends, and you can jump from file to file, change order, etc.

Comment: Didn't know that this feature is right there all these time! Thanks!